# Can't use 127.0.0.1 to connect mysql server docker container, but can use IP?

Tags: mysql, docker

In my personal PC, there's a docker mysql container binding with port 3306. It works well. 
I can connect the mysql server in this container over another PC.

```
sh$ mysql -hxxx.xxx.xxx.110 -uroot -p
```

In the host PC, I can connect the container by this way:

```
sh$ mysql -hxxx.xxx.xxx.110 -uroot -p
```

But when I try to connect the container to 127.0.0.1, it fails:

```
sh$ mysql -uroot -p
```

Known:

1. In the container, I can connect the mysql server by:

   ```
      sh$ mysql -uroot -p
   ```
2. there's nothing wrong with the password
3. Meanwhile, I can connect 127.0.0.1:6376 over the host to the redis container....

Answer (score 2):

I'm only speculating, but the Docker container likely has its own [pseudo] network interface. But you're trying to connect over the host's loopback interface. Those are two separate networks.

Remember, 127.0.0.1 is not just a special IP — it's an IP assigned by a separate network interface.

You can configure Docker to share the host's network stack; perhaps that would be best here.

Answer (score 0):

Please try follow steps:
1.login mysql with ip and use "select host,user,password from mysql.user;" to check 127.0.0.1 exists or not in command result;
[image]

2.if not please execute grant command and ensure 127.0.0.1 has privileges,then tray login again.

```
grant all on *.* to root@'127.0.0.1' identified by 'root';
flush privileges;
```

Comment: In order to make it easy, I had already grant all privileges on *.* to root@'%' identified by '...';   flush privileges;   -_!   So your suggestion may not works, I guess.

Comment: Sorry, `no works` means `no helpful` .... I had already grant '%' (all address) ... includes localhost

Answer (score -1):

You're going to want to check your `my.cnf` for the `bind-address` configuration:

```
# 
# File: my.cnf
#
[mysqld]
bind-address            = 192.168.1.100
```

In good practice and depending on your use-case, this should be `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Obviously not! As you can notice that I can connect through 127.0.0.1 in the container. So there must be nothing wrong with bind-address --> without doubt, I had commented the bind-address already.